# what about $\lim\limits_{x\to0}-\frac{\sin x}x=$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

we all know that:

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$

so what is the negative

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}-\frac{\sin x}x=$?

i am trying to prove what about  $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin \frac 1x}{\sin^2 x}$

i got to $\frac{-x^2}{\sin^2 x} \le $ $\frac{x^2\sin \frac 1x}{\sin^2 x}\le$$\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}$

and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}= \lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x= 1\times1=1  $

and$\lim\limits_{x\to0}-\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}= \lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x\lim\limits_{x\to0}-\frac{\sin x}x=?$

Comment: Since $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(-1\right)$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\dfrac {\sin (x)}x\right)$ both exist..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put,

> $$\lim_{x\to a} (Af(x))=A\lim_{x\to a} f(x),\text{ where $A$ is a constant.}$$
>   So let $A=-1$ in your expression.

**Edit:** Let me generalize:

If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x),\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist, then $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)g(x))$ exists. So, let $g(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x},f(x)=-1$.

Comment: so you actually saying that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x\lim\limits_{x\to0}-\frac{\sin x}x = \lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x\lim\limits_{x\to0}(-1)$ 
so i can use squeeze theorem to find answer for   $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin \frac 1x}{\sin^2 x}$

Comment: The limit is just $-1$, as $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=f(x),A=-1$, and as $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1$, $\lim_{x\to0}-\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=-1$.

Comment: so   $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin \frac 1x}{\sin^2 x}$
dont have a limit

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}= \lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x= 1\times1=1  $ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}-\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}= \lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x\lim\limits_{x\to0}-\frac{\sin x}x=-1$, so what do you get?

Comment: $-1\le\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin \frac 1x}{\sin^2 x}\le1$

Comment: @user134853 Yes, that's true.

Comment: @user134853 Also, note that the limit does not exist - see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+goes+to+0+of+%28x%5E2+sin%281%2Fx%29%29%2F%28%28sin+x%29%5E2%29.

Comment: so it mean that the limit on $0^+$ is $1$ and on$0^-$ it is $-1$
so in $x=0$ there is no limit
this is how i explain it in mathematical point of view?

Comment: @user134853 The left and right limits are not the same, hence the limit does not exist.